# How to structure your android layout with software buttons?

Tags: android, layout, button, user-interface

I'm currently working on a project that needs to be compatible with tablets and phones. I've been trying to find out how to structure or program your layout to deal with software buttons because these buttons actually take about .5 inch of the screen but I can't find any good documentation. Would you actually make a whole new layout and use that one when the device has software buttons and another one when the device has physical ones?

Comment: there is an official guide to supporting different screen sizes here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: For some reason I can't access the website. Is it down for you too?

Comment: yea it seems to be down right now.